# where to find oneplus one binaries (Device tree, Vendor, Kernel) to build rom from AOSP?

Tags: android, driver, android-source, rom, oneplusone

I would like to build ROM for one plus one from AOSP (android 5.1.1)
Look like i need below three information from the device manufacturer and override it in local_manifest.xml

1. Device Tree'
2. Vendor
3. Kernel.

I am able to get Device tree and Kernel. I am not able to find Vendor binaries for one plus one.
anybody can help me to get this?
Below is the local_manifest.xml i have. But it is missing vendor information.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

`<manifest>`

`<remote  name="github" fetch="https://github.com/"/>`
  `<project path="device/oneplusone/one" name="CyanogenMod/android_device_oneplus_bacon"   remote="github" revision="cm-12.0" />`

`<project path="kernel/oneplusone/one" name="CyanogenMod/android_kernel_oneplus_msm8974" remote="github" revision="cm-12.0" />`

`</manifest>`

Answer (score 1):

Obviously due to legal concerns CyanogenMod can not post vendors. So they use this secondary account - https://github.com/TheMuppets

All vendors, including the OnePlus One `bacon` can be found [here](https://github.com/TheMuppets/proprietary_vendor_oneplus)