# Android Porting Device Configuration

Tags: android, configuration, device, android-source, porting

I was forking device config on github.

It had mk files and some folders.

Well, the mk files are already defined its usage by another stackoverflow question: [Android device configuration for AOSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352709/android-device-configuration-for-aosp)

But, what about the folders like audio, bluetooth, power, camera?

How can I get it, and what is it?

Plus, CM Porting guide says forking a similar hardware device's configuration may help.

But how can I exactly compare these hardwares?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The bulk of the AOSP source tree is included when you run `repo sync` including all of the necessary framework files.

Vendor specific binaries for the device hardware can be downloaded for the target device from https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/drivers assuming you're building to a Nexus device. These are self-extracting scripts that will create the vendor/ directly, then you can compile your system image.

For other devices, some are released by the manufacturer and others are available from 3rd parties, see this question: [where to find oneplus one binaries (Device tree, Vendor, Kernel) to build rom from AOSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696395/where-to-find-oneplus-one-binaries-device-tree-vendor-kernel-to-build-rom-fr)